# How do I use Java Spark Framework queryMaps?

Tags: java, spark-framework

My Html is of the form

```
     <input type="hidden" name="SONGS" value="6242,6243,6289,6290,6291,6292,6293,6294,6295,6296,6297,6298,">

 <tr>
    <td>
        01 - Big Love.WAV
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="6242TRACK" value="01">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="6242ARTIST" value="Fleetwood Mac">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="6242ARTIST_SORT" value="Fleetwood Mac">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="6242TITLE" value="Big Love">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        02 - Seven Wonders.WAV
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="6243TRACK" value="02">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="6243ARTIST" value="Fleetwood Mac">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="6243ARTIST_SORT" value="Fleetwood Mac">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="6243TITLE" value="Seven Wonders">
    </td>
</tr>
```

When user submits the form data it is processed using Spark framework. My logic was get the list of recnos from the SONGS input field, and then for each recNo browse the input fields starting with that recno. But its not working, **I think I am misunderstanding how queryMaps work**

```
protected void saveData(Request req)
    {
       String[] recNos = req.queryParams(EditSongsPage.SONGS).split(",");
       for(String recNo:recNos)
       {
           System.out.println("recNo--------------"+recNo);
           for(String next:req.queryMap(recNo).values())
           {

               System.out.println(next);
           }
       }

    }
```

but this gives

```
recNo--------------6242
02/03/2018 08.58.22:GMT:com.jthink.songkong.server.callback.ServerEditSongs:startTask:SEVERE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at spark.QueryParamsMap.values(QueryParamsMap.java:262)
    at com.jthink.songkong.server.callback.ServerEditSongs.saveData(ServerEditSongs.java:80)
    at com.jthink.songkong.server.callback.ServerEditSongs.startTask(ServerEditSongs.java:52)
    at com.jthink.songkong.server.CmdRemote.lambda$null$62(CmdRemote.java:171)
    at spark.RouteImpl$1.handle(RouteImpl.java:72)
    at spark.http.matching.Routes.execute(Routes.java:61)
    at spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:130)
    at spark.embeddedserver.jetty.JettyHandler.doHandle(JettyHandler.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1568)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:591)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: There is no `req.queryMap(recNo)` input in your form, therefore your NPE, You may want to try: `req.queryMap(recNo + "TRACK")` you see how your inputs are named?

Comment: How does it differ from queryParamValues() then ?

Comment: It doesn't you are trying to get something that isn't there. You see, the name of the parameters are what you give in the `<input name="thisIsAName"..../>` what you trying to do is getTheParamenterWithTheName("thisIsA") it simple doesn't exists in the collection of parameters.

Comment: Find, but Im not getting what the point of queryMap is ?

Comment: QueryMap is a hashmap object (which means key, value pairs) that stores the request parameters and its values from a submitted web page. On it will will have all key-pairs of you inputs like: `6242TRACK-01;  6242ARTIST-Fleetwood Mac` and so on... That's why it is not working.

Comment: Okay thanks Ive now realized a purpose for it, I had a request object which I then passed to a runnable task that processed in another thread, but it dint work because when came to run the query params were reset. If I passed the queryMap instead that data would still exist when the task run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *QueryMap* copies the contents of request parameters from a *HttpRequest* and put the values into a map keyed by parameter name.

Because the contents of the *HttpRequest* are copied then the values of the querymap can be passed to a process on another thread and used accordingly, whereas the contents of the *HttpRequest* object are wiped once the page that recieved the request has sent back a *HttpResponse*.

That seems to be the main advantage of a *QueryMap*